# Calling JavaScript Function on Demand Causing Strange Results

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dropdownlist which is declared as follows:

```
<select onchange="reloadValues(this,event);">
... options here 
</select>
```

When the user change the selection reloadValues is invoked and everything works perfectly. Now, I want to add the reloadValues when the user adds a new row which contains the dropdownlist so I did the following:

```
reloadValues(rowToBeAdded.find("select")[0]);
```

The reloadValues function is shown below:

```
 function reloadValues(obj, event) {
    {
            var ele = obj.parentElement.parentElement;
            var select2 = ele.cells[2].childNodes[1]; // ele.cells is empty when invoking // the reloadValues on demand through another method. 
    }
```

Any ideas!

```
obj.parentElement.parentElement is a TR element
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hit this problem once because I was accessing `cells` before the `<tr>` element was added to the document. At least Internet Explorer 8 returns an empty cell collection in this situation.

So, try appending `rowToBeAdded` to your table before calling `reloadValues()`.